# How can I calculate the tens place value of 2^100 in C++?

Tags: c++, math, integer-overflow

How can I calculate the tens place value of 2^100 in C++?

I tried this;

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int answer;
    answer = (unsigned long long int)pow(2, 100) % 100 / 10; //zero
    cout << answer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But it printed 0 because of overflow.

Python prints the answer correctly with this code;

```
print(2 ** 100 % 100 // 10)
```

But how do I calculate it in C++?

Comment: You could potentially use `fmod` instead of `%` to calculate mod for floating point numbers

Comment: Use a compiler that support 128 bit integers or use a big number library...

Comment: `long long int` is likely not large enough to store 2^100

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm preparing KOI(Korean Olympiad in Informatics). So, I'm solving last year's KOI problems. Calculating the tens value of 2^100 is last year's KOI problem. See problem 9 in https://koi.or.kr/assets/koi/2021/1/problems/e1-problems.pdf(Use translator if you don't know Korean. ).

Comment: @Phil1970 Is there a data type thar supports 128 bit integers?

Comment: Since 2 to the 100th power is `1267650600228229401496703205376`, you could just take the `7`.

Comment: I suppose that's true, then. Still, you must understand, that very, very few people in the world care about that, comparatively speaking. The partial correct answer here is to use `fmod`. However before that can happen you must have `2^100`, exactly, and you will not get that from `pow()`. Using `pow()` with two integer values is always wrong. That's not what it's for. You must calculate `2^100` by multiplication of `double` values.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank for your answer. I changed `%` to `fmod`, and the code printed 7.

Comment: I don't know if it's "most" or "some", Jack. But I don't recall being asked anything like that in my career. Definitely nothing of that sort was asked when I interviewed at a company where last year I celebrated my 10th anniversary, with.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: 2^100 is exactly representable as a double.

Comment: It is, @PresidentJamesK.Polk but `pow(2, 100)` is not guaranteed to be exactly 2^100. Do you know how `pow()` works?

Comment: I would guess that pow uses log and exp and other similar tricks but I'd also suspect that it has special cases for things like integer arguments. However, your point stands, it's not guaranteed to be 2^100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with typecasting.

As you can see from documentation [std::pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) return `double`

So first step to solve our problem, try to remove type casting.

```cpp
std::pow(2, 100); // return 1.26765e+30
```

The next problem we can't use operator `%` with `double` type so we need [std::fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)
So final solution would look like this:

```cpp
int answer = std::fmod(std::pow(2, 100), 100) / 10;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just do it in 2 steps:

```
int x = (1<<25)%100;
x = (x*x*x*x)%100;
x = x/10;
```

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned long long int` is not large enough to store 2**100. If you are using GCC or Clang, try to use `__int128` instead.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int answer = ((__int128)std::pow(2, 100)) % 100 / 10;
  std::cout << answer << '\n'; // 7
}
```

Comment: I think that using `<<`  with `__int128` arguments might be safer...